# What strategies are there for assembling Azure Function microservices into transactions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Looking into Azure Functions as a way of expressing small pieces of business logic, so that they can be assembled into 'units of work.' Perhaps by creating new Functions that invoke the others, perhaps by Logic Apps, not sure. In general, how can these agglomerations of Functions be executed as a transaction... can db contexts and service bus transactions be passed around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What strategies are there for assembling Azure Function microservices into transactions?

For micro service, eventual consistency is more suitable than strong transactional consistency. You could find more information of the context and solution of transaction for micro services from following link.

[Compensating Transaction pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/compensating-transaction)

*Applications running in the cloud frequently modify data. This data might be spread across various data sources held in different geographic locations. To avoid contention and improve performance in a distributed environment, an application shouldn't try to provide strong transactional consistency. Rather, the application should implement eventual consistency. In this model, a typical business operation consists of a series of separate steps.*

> can db contexts and service bus transactions be passed around?

These transactions are worked in different level than the service level transaction. Compensating Transaction is only a pattern recommended by Microsoft. We need to implement it by ourselves to make it suitable for your services.